# Simple list concatenating function (intersperse) in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to write an *intersperse* function that takes a list of lists of `a` e.g. a list of Strings, and one single `a` e.g. a `char` as a separator and returns a list of `a` or a String.

For example, if I call

```hs
intersperse ',' ["a", "b"]
-- I will get "a,b"

intersperse ',' ["hello"]
-- I will get only "hello"

intersperse ',' ["a", "b", "c"]
-- I will get "a,b,c"

intersperse 1 [[2,3,4], [5,6,7]]
-- I will get [2, 3, 4, 1, 5, 6, 7]

intersperse 1 [[2,3], [4,5], [6,7]]
-- I will get [2, 3, 1, 4, 5, 1, 6, 7]
--
```

So I wrote it as follows and it works fine.

```hs
intersperse :: a -> [[a]] -> [a]
intersperse s [] = []
intersperse s (x:[]) = x
intersperse s (x:xs) = loop x xs
  where loop a [] = a
        loop a (x:xs) = loop (a ++ [s] ++ x) xs
```

**But if I add type signature to the loop function it will not compile, and I can't realise what's wrong**

```hs
intersperse :: a -> [[a]] -> [a]
intersperse s [] = []
intersperse s (x:[]) = x
intersperse s (x:xs) = loop x xs
  where loop :: [a] -> [[a]] -> [a]
        loop a [] = a
        loop a (x:xs) = loop (a ++ [s] ++ x) xs
```

Comment: That is because the `a` in the `where` clause is a different one than the one at the top level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But if I add type signature to the loop function it will not compile, and I can't realise what's wrong.

That is because the `a` in the `where` clause is a different one than the one at the top level. You can enable the [**`ScopedTypeVariables`** extension [ghc-doc]](https://downloads.haskell.org/%7Eghc/8.4.2/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#extension-ScopedTypeVariables) for this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

intersperse :: forall a. a -> [[a]] -> [a]
intersperse s [] = []
intersperse s (x : []) = x
intersperse s (x : xs) = loop x xs
  where
    loop :: [a] -> [[a]] -> [a]
    loop a [] = a
    loop a (x : xs) = loop (a ++ [s] ++ x) xs
```

The `intersperse` function is not written lazily however, this means that for large lists, it will take a lot of time before the result is handed to the caller, and will consume a lot of memory, and for infinite lists, it will get in an infinite loop that will end when memory is exhausted.

You can optimize the function with:

```
intersperse :: a -> [[a]] -> [a]
intersperse s [] = []
intersperse s [x] = x
intersperse s (x : xs) = x ++ go xs
  where
    go [] = []
    go (x : xs) = s : x ++ go xs
```

Comment: Isn't lazy evaluation the default behavior in Haskell? Or are you referring to *tail recursion*?

I'm also still getting the same error on *Haskell For Mac* IDE for the following program
```

Comment: @ehsun7b: yes. but you need to ensure that it *can* be lazy. Your function keeps working with recursion and keeps the result it is building in the accumulator, and that result is only "released" at the end. Haskell's interpreter is indeed lazy, that does not mean that all functions are maximally lazy, since if you call it with a list and the `intersperse 1 [[1], [2]]` for example needs to be evaluated, you typically want already a (partial) result for `[[1]]`, not when it has evaluated `[[2]]` as well.

Comment: So to get it clear, your version can leverage lazy evaluation because the `go` function is tail recursive?

Comment: @ehsun7b: no in fact it is because it is not tail recursive. Indeed, `go` just emits `s : x ++ go xs`, so only if we need more data after the `s : x ++ ...` part, the `go` will evaluate the rest of the list, so this is a "break point" where the consumer can be happy and thus terminate enumerating over the list.